# vb.net Slowdown foreach statement

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using this code

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item + ":" + item)
```

How could i slow this down so my program won't freeze.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: if you're using the 4.5 version of .net framework? you can use the http://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Comment: How many items are there that this freezes? Anyway, this *just might* be a case where DoEvents could help, although using a queue or stream (and batching/yielding additions) would be my general solution.

Comment: @spajce I'm actually unsure how async/TPL would work here because the primary work needs to be done on the UI thread to avoid cross-thread exceptions when adding to a Winform UI element.

Comment: You could add a thread.Sleep(50); it is the answer because the question is: How to slow down the foreach

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: That will just make it worse.

Answer (score 1):

Call `BeginUpdate()` before the loop, and `EndUpdate()` after it, so that the listbox only updates once.

Comment: @user2900414: How didn't it work? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use the DoEvents()  This tells your UI Thread to see if there are other messages that need to be processed, like your UI changes.  Warning, this will allow the user to CLICK on your buttons, close your form, etc. You need to lock things down so the user cannot click the button twice or close the form while it is running.  Also, I usually avoid running DoEvents in EVERY loop. It depends on your situation and what you are dong in your loop but every 100 should work in the example you posted.

```
Dim iLoop as int32 = 0
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
  ListBox2.Items.Add(item + ":" + item)
  iLoop += 1
  If i mod 100 = 0 then 'Only runs 1 out of 100 times
    system.windows.forms.application.doevents()
  end if
next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Delegate Sub dlgUpdateUI(ByVal text As String)
Private t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf updateListbox)

Private Sub updateListbox()

    For Each item In ListBox1.Items

        If ListBox2.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New dlgUpdateUI(AddressOf updateListbox)
            ListBox2.Invoke(d, Text)
        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item & ":" & item)
        End If

    Next
```

---

```
t.Start()
```

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29

Comment: This should only add n-items (or add items for x-time) at once or it will result in the same behavior - once the control is on the UI thread it will still "freeze", as we're back to the original issue.

Comment: This will call `ListBox2.Items.Add(item & ":" & item)` n^2 times. Inside the `For Each` loop, `ListBox2.InvokeRequired`, you should exit the loop upon return.